# NMDS plot output not matching the dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan, mds

I am trying to plot an ordination plot for NMDS scores in R but I am noticing an issue regarding the point_color and point_shape are not matching for each point. For example site 31 and 35 are both Group 1, and will be triangles and colored orange in the dataset. However, the plot inputs site 31 as blue. It does that a few times so it seems to be an issue with the color. [image]
[image]

```
`ggplot(terranmds.data_scorestest, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(site), shape = factor(Group)), 
             size = 3, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = site, colour = factor(site)), vjust = 1.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(
    title = "Measured Communities Ordination Plot (August)",
    colour = "Year Communities",
    shape = "Temp. Grouping"
  ) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = terranmds.data_scorestest$point_color, guide = "none") +  # Remove color legend +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1, linetype = "solid"),
    legend.position = c(0.05, 0.05),
    legend.justification = c(0, 0),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12, color = "grey14", face = "bold")
  ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "#45ADA8", size = 15, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "grey")`

I am trying to plot an ordination plot for NMDS scores in R but I am noticing an issue regarding the point_color and point_shape are not matching for each point. For example site 31 and 35 are both Group 1, and will be triangles and colored orange in the dataset. However, the plot inputs site 31 as blue. It does that a few times so it seems to be an issue with the color. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRWYF.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JTQQ.png

`ggplot(terranmds.data_scorestest, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(site), shape = factor(Group)), 
             size = 3, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = site, colour = factor(site)), vjust = 1.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(
    title = "Measured Communities Ordination Plot (August)",
    colour = "Year Communities",
    shape = "Temp. Grouping"
  ) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = terranmds.data_scorestest$point_color, guide = "none") +  # Remove color legend +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1, linetype = "solid"),
    legend.position = c(0.05, 0.05),
    legend.justification = c(0, 0),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12, color = "grey14", face = "bold")
  ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "#45ADA8", size = 15, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "grey")`
```

Comment: Could be something to do with factor levels? Try setting the levels prior to plotting:
`terranmds.data_scorestest$site <- factor(terranmds.data_scorestest$site, levels = unique(terranmds.data_scorestest$site))`

Comment: Changing the factor levels beforehand seems to have done the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use column values as the colour try `scale_colour_identity()` instead!

Comment: Using `scale_colour_identity()` I get an error message: Error in discrete_scale(aesthetics, "identity", identity_pal(), ..., guide = guide,  : 
  unused argument (values = c("blue", "blue",..."orange"))

Comment: Rather than specifying the values as the column of the data.frame, try instead adding the colour to your aes(). It's hard to troubleshoot without your data, but (for example), this should work:

`df = data.frame(x = seq(1,5,1), y = seq(1,5,1), col = c("red","yellow","green","blue","purple"))`


`df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = col)) + scale_colour_identity()`

While this throws an error:

`df %>%  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_identity(values = df$col)`

(Apologies for my atrocious formatting)